# SendGrid - Not getting custom_args returned on bounce events

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

When sending emails through SendGrid's Node mail client ("@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0") we are adding some custom_args to the JSON submitted and all of them are text values.  The webhooks for processed, delivered, open, and click events return the custom_args to us as expected.  But when we receive a webhook for the bounce event the custom_args are not attached.

We are submitting:

````
{ personalizations: [ 
    { to: {
        email: 'recipient@example.com',
        name: 'Recipient Name'
      } 
    } 
  ],
  from:
   { 
      email: 'sender@example.com',
      name: 'Sender Name' 
   },
  reply: { 
    email: 'replyto@example.com', 
    name: 'Reply To Name' 
  },
  custom_args:
   { envelopeId: '4aa4f5f8-9ba4-4ec3-a6cf-3098107f498d',
     messageId: '105',
     eventId: '251' },
  subject: 'Test Email 1234',
  content:
   [ { type: 'text/plain',
       value:
        'This is a sample email, please click here: https://example.com' },
     { type: 'text/html',
       value:
        'This is a sample email, please <a href=\'https://example.com\'>click here</a>' } ],
  mail_settings: { sandbox_mode: { enable: false } } }```
````

Answer (score 3):

Got an answer back from SendGrid on this one.  The issue is when a mail server does a slow bounce where it takes them some time to sort out that they do not have anyone with that name locally, then they sometimes return a brand new email to the sending server and that causes SendGrid to loose all of the context that was placed in the initial email.

Comment: well that's annoying

Comment: Is this still the state of play? I'm guessing so... just thinking custom args sure are useless if this is the case in terms of webhook event inspection goes!

Comment: Haven't been working with them of late, but I would imagine so.  They are useful when they are there, but these long bounces... Yeah, it is an issue.

Comment: Can confirm that this still seems to be a problem in May 2022.